# $x=(x^2)^k$ for a finite group where $x$ has an odd order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a question about the following exercise from Dummit & Foote's Abstract Algebra (Sec. 1.1, q. 21):

> Let $G$ be a finite group and let $x$ be an element of $G$ of order $n$. Prove that if $n$ is odd, then $x=(x^2)^k$ for some integer $k\geq 1$.

The post: [Property of odd ordered elements of a Group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1819208/property-of-odd-ordered-elements-of-a-group) already has a proof given on it. But I have a different question. Let me know if I should have rather posted it on to that thread instead.

Anyway consider:

$x^n = 1$

Then:

$x\cdot x^{n-1} = 1 \implies x^{n-1}=x^{-1}$

Since $n-1$ is even, there exists an integer $k\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that $2k=n-1$. Thus:

$x^{2k} = (x^2)^k = x^{-1}$

But then if the assertion that this exercise is making is true, then:

$x^{-1} = x$

Have we not arrived a contradiction? I cannot seem to find the error in my proof so all help is appreciated.

Comment: No, there's no contradiction. You can't assert $x^{-1} = x$ since you can't claim that you have the same value of $k$.

Comment: Ohhh, I got it, thank you very much... can't believe I overlooked that...

Comment: In other words, you found a values of $k$ such that $(x^2)^k = x^{-1}$. That need not be the same value of $k$ such that $(x^2)^k=x$.

Comment: Ok. I'll post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no contradiction. You can't assert $x^{-1}=x$, since you can't claim that you have the same value of $k$.

In other words, you found a value of $k$ such that $(x^2)^k=x^{−1}$. That need not be the same value of $k$ such that $(x^2)^k=x$.

If for some $x$, the values of $k$ *were* the same, then in that case, you *would* have $x^{-1}=x$. But that would imply $x^2 = 1$, hence, since $x$ has odd order, $x$ would have to be $1$.